# Selected checkboxes in a repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to get all of the IDs of selected checkboxes in an ASP Repeater, however I can't seem to get the values. Heres what I have for code (cut down):

```
  protected void rptFire_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            DataRowView nRow = null;

            switch (e.Item.ItemType)
            {
                case ListItemType.Item:
                case ListItemType.AlternatingItem:
                  nRow = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;

                    ((CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("cbSelectedItem")).Attributes.Add("data-Sel", LocID);
                    break; 

            }

}
```

The above is setting an ID to go on the the data-set

The checkbox is:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelectedItem" CssClass="cEditItem" runat="server" />
```

The javascript is:

```
   $(".editItem").click(function () {
         var chkId = '';
         $('.cEditItem:checked').each(function () {
             chkId += $(this).data("sel") + ",";
         });
         chkId = chkId.slice(0, -1);
         alert(chkId);
         return false;
     });
```

However whatever is selected and clicked the alert pops up twice but the chkId is always empty.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should read custom data attribute "data-Sel" which you added using below code.

```
((CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("cbSelectedItem")).Attributes.Add("data-Sel", LocID);
```

Now, this the code which work as you want.

```
$(".editItem").click(function () {
    var chkId = '';
       $('input:checkbox').each(function () {
           var sThisVal = (this.checked ? $(this).attr("data-Sel") : "");

           if(sThisVal.length > 0)
               chkId += sThisVal + ",";
      });
    chkId = chkId.slice(0, -1);
    alert(chkId);
});
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aQJq9/)